# ls command not working under ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, server, 16.04, ls

I looked up this question of [ls command not working in ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518263/ls-command-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04]).

I get the exact same error.

```
ls: unrecognized option '--color=auto'
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) multicall binary.
```

Here is the output of the question @Eliah Kagan asked in the comment for the above question:
**$mount**
[image: mount command output]

**$df -h**
[image: df h option]

**type -a ls**
[image: type -a ls]

**file /bin/ls**
[image: file /bin/ls]

**ls command output**

```
ls: unrecognized option '--color=auto'
BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) multicall binary.
```

**lsb_release output**
[image: lsb_release output]

**apt-cache policy coreutils**
[image: apt-cache policy coreutils]

I was looking at grub.cfg and I did not save any changes but when I exited, I started getting this error. Can someone provide pointers of any possible fix?

Comment: Eliah Kagan's questions from the comments of your linked question are just as relevant here: please try to answer them, and [edit] your question with the outputs

Comment: Can you `edit` your question to include the output from the terminal when you type `alias`? (Looking at grub.cfg didn't cause the `ls` command to fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

examine your current definition of ls

```
type ls
```

it will typically respond with

```
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
```

if not then take a look inside your ~/.bashrc and look for this section which is there by default ... if its not there put it back into ~/.bashrc

```
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```

its where the alias is defined by default  ... is your shell bash ?

```
echo $SHELL
```

if it shows you

```
/bin/bash
```

then above will fix the issue ... once done open a new terminal or source your settings

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

ls will now be OK

If its not OK then just remove your ls alias in your ~/.bashrc (hint your ls is coming from busybox which is not adhering to standard ls)

`~/.bashrc`contains personalizations which augment system wide default of

```
/etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: I managed to get it working after deleting `~/.bashrc`. I don't understand why .bashrc is a cause for this issue.